# Exporting attribute table that has many rows in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, excel

I checked previous questions that could be related with this question but none of them gave me an answer.

I need to know how to export attribute table that has many rows inside. I have over 2.5 million rows in the attribute table and I cannot export it to excel or as .txt format.

After exporting that data, I will work on it with Microsoft Access Software.

If there is a way to do it, please someone explain it.

Comment: Have you tries to save your table as CSV file?

Comment: What is the problem with .txt?

Comment: @ahmadhanb it doesn't work either.

Comment: @user30184 I don't know. I selected all features and try to export it as .txt file. However, it gives error.

Comment: @Icarus - Can you please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/218678/edit) your question to include the error message? =)

Comment: .csv format is working now. Somehow I did mistake before. Thank you guys for all your attention

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can export your attribute table to a CSV file format which can handle big files. To export the attribute table, right-click the layer in the table of content `-> Save as ->` choose `Comma Separated File (CSV)` from `Format` drop-down list:

[image]